# Как сделать так, что бы бот после определенного сообщения отправлял сообщение в беседу Телеграм

Tags: python, бот

Пишу бота на Python. Не могу понять как сделать что бы бот после получения сообщения определенного, отправлял сообщение в группу где он есть.

Какую команду мне написать что бы сообщение отправилось в группу/беседу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> @dp.message_handler(content_type = 'text')
> async def send_msg(message: types.Message):
>     await bot.send_message(ID_CHAT, message.text)
> ```

Comment: Под телеграм, старно, выше вроде писал, НО БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! И извиняюсь за малую конкретику.

Comment: прошу прощения, не увидел.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать еще один момент? Что нужно написать в коде, что бы БОТ ждал сообщение от юзера, после чего пересылал написанное сообщение в беседу?

Comment: Если вы используете библиотеку Aiogram для написания логики бота, то вам нужна машина состояний.
сыль: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/
оф сыль: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html
я разбирался по последней ссылке, мне кажется там все прямолинейно и понятно без воды.